# mysql how to use parameters in CURSOR?

Tags: parameters, cursor

it does not work. The CURSOR parameters are unknown.
How could we use the parameter in this case? Big thanks

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proUpdateMember(inDate Date)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_memberId INT;
    DECLARE dueDate, lastTwelfthDueDate date;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

    DECLARE UpdateMember(inDueDate date ,inLastTwelfthDueDate date) 
            CURSOR FOR select member_id from tableMember where
                member_due_date BETWEEN inLastTwelfthDueDate and inDueDate; 

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    set dueDate = (inDate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
    set lastTwelfthDueDate = (dueDate - INTERVAL 12 MONTH);

    OPEN UpdateMember(dueDate,lastTwelfthDueDate); /* input parameter */
        read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH UpdateMember INTO v_memberId;
        IF done THEN LEAVE read_loop; END IF;
            select v_memberId;
        end if;
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE UpdateMember;
END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact we do not need to use the parameter input for `CURSOR`.
It works properly as below:

```mysql
CREATE PROCEDURE proUpdateMember(inDate Date)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_memberId INT;
    DECLARE dueDate, lastTwelfthDueDate date;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

    DECLARE UpdateMember 
            CURSOR FOR select member_id from tableMember where
                member_due_date BETWEEN inLastTwelfthDueDate and inDueDate; 

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    set dueDate = (inDate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
    set lastTwelfthDueDate = (dueDate - INTERVAL 12 MONTH);

    OPEN UpdateMember;
        read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH UpdateMember INTO v_memberId;
        IF done THEN LEAVE read_loop; END IF;
            select v_memberId;
        end if;
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE UpdateMember;
END$$
```

Comment: Do I get this right -- your trick is to not use a parameter for the cursor but to access a variable inside the cursor that you just have to set before opening the cursor?

Answer (score 0):

In case you can choose:

From **MariaDB** 10.3.0, cursors can have parameters - 
see a ggod example here https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/cursor-overview/

example: **CURSOR(...)**

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR(pmin INT, pmax INT) FOR SELECT
```